# if else failing regex

Tags: regex

I want to write a regex to find if word is of 3 characters length, but preceding by `m_` is optional. In that case `m_` followed by minimum of 3 characters is required.

Basically I want to match

`Abc` or `m_abc` and dont match `ab` or `m_ac`

```
(^(m_))?([a-zA-Z0-9_]{3,})|(^[a-zA-Z0-9_]{3,}$)
```

I tried an if loop but it is matching the text `m_a` also.
Can you please help me what I am missing here

Maybe I wrote my regex wrong. 
I want something like
if(m_ found)
     "followed by 3 characters required"
else
     "Look if total number of characters is 3"

Thanks.

Comment: Things go wrong because you made `^` optional as well.

Comment: What language or regex parser are you using? The example you've provided appears to be ERE, but if your parser supports PCRE, more options would be available to you....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use this regular expression, which either requires the `m_` at the start or forbids it (by negative look-ahead):

```
^(m_|(?!m_))\w{3,}$
```

See [regex tester](https://regex101.com/r/iQ8cQ6/1)

If negative look-head is not a feature you can use, then you could go for this more elaborate regex, which goes through the different options for the first two characters:

```
^(m_\w{3,}|m[A-Za-z0-9]\w+|[A-Za-ln-z0-9]\w{2,})$
```

See [regex tester](https://regex101.com/r/qH1jD5/1)

Comment: Thanks a lot it works. But sorry I have more to ask. I thought that i can extend if I know basic but I am not able to extend.                         Is it possible to add g_ also. It is like m_ or g_ are allowed

Comment: To extend with `g_`: `^(m_|g_|(?!m_)(?!g_))\w{3,}$`

Comment: or shorter: `^([mg]_|(?![mg]_))\w{3,}$`

Answer (score 0):

Do you want your 3-character word to be able to have underscores in it? Because if not, then you can change `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` to `[a-zA-Z0-9]`, and it should not match `m_a` in that case. And unless you want to match numerals, you can simplify it further to `[a-zA-z]`.

Comment: Thanks for reply aaron. Yes my requirement is to match _ also. It is for detecting if code is written as per standards. Variable like "Test_Val" is valid

Comment: Ah, okay. In that case, why is `m_a` not a valid variable name?

Comment: If m_ is found at first then it should be followed by 3 characters. If it is not found then as you said yes we can allow something like a_b.

Answer (score 0):

The main error is that the `^` line anchor is inside the optional parenthesized expression.  You want beginning of line unconditionally, followed by an optional `m_?`.

You can simplify the rest significantly.  Three or more is captured by an expression which requires three characters; the regex will succeed at that point, whether or not you are at the end of the input.

```
^(m_)?[a-zA-Z0-9_]{3}
```

The underscore in the character class seems somewhat dubious.  Do you really intend for a "word" to include underscores?  Then `m_ac` will also match, because it is at least three characters long and consists of characters in the set, even though you say it is specifically disallowed.